# Titanium sqlite table database

Tags: javascript, ios, sqlite, titanium, titanium-mobile

So i am trying to create a database for my titanium application, i have done the sql file but when ever i try and run it with the code i have it simply doesn't work, can anyone point me in the direction of a good tutorial for this type of thing. Im trying to create the database that has a tableview and once clicking on a tableView list item it goes to its child list and once clicking on one of those list items it will add it to the "List" which will be saved and able to be viewed in a different screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check following links :

- [Titanium database tutorial](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/88241/titanium-database-tutorial-posted)
- [Titanium docs guide](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Working+with+a+SQLite+Database)
- [Titanium Alloy using backbone model](http://www.itexico.com/blog/bid/95789/Mobile-App-Tutorial-Backbone-Models-Database-with-Titanium-Alloy)

Edit : Few more Alloy DB links :

- [Alloy MVC example](http://luiselizondo.net/blogs/luis-elizondo/alloy-and-titanium-studio-part-2-controllers-views-collections-and-models-and)
- [Alloy MVC full project](https://github.com/aaronksaunders/alloy_fugitive)

Hope this will help.